# Jquery to find the last nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand the use of using .last() or :last-child etc. to get the last sibling of an element, but how would one get the most inner elements text() with the same tag name without using any classes or ids?

For example:

```
$(body).find('div').text();
```

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>Get this text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>And get this text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I have used a loop to return the text on each div using $.each, I am returning duplications of text for each div's text().

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could select `div` elements that don't contain a child element by combining the [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors. This essentially negates all `div` elements that have a child:

```
$('div:not(:has(*))').text();
```

If you want an array text strings:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j61ymnm1/)

```
var textArray = $('div:not(:has(*))').map(function (_, el) {
    return el.innerText;
}).get();

console.log(textArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherently recursive problem and the following does the job too:

```
function getText(elem) {
    if (elem.children().length === 0) {
        console.log( elem.html() );
    } else {
        elem.children().each( function() {
                getText($(this));
            }
        );
    }
}

getText( $('div').first() );
```